# Making http request from aws codebuild buildspec file to an EC2 instance which is in EKS cluster

Tags: rest, microservices, amazon-eks, aws-codebuild, single-spa

I have AWS codebuild buildspec ym file and a pod in EKS cluster, I need to run some logic in the pod triggered from buildspec file through http request.

I have buildspec as the follwoing:
`post_build: commands: - curl http://service-name.eks_cluster_name:8000/blabla`

but it exist with status code 6, meaning could not **resolve service-name.eks_cluster_name** domain name ?

Any help to make it works or a workaround, would appreciated ?

Thank you

tried `- curl http://service-name.eks_cluster_name:8000/blabla` but domain name could not be resolved.
I'm expecting that the serive **service-name.eks_cluster_name:8000** to be reachable from aws codebuild buildspec ?